# Meaning of at sign at the beginning and at end of a variable

Tags: bash, libreoffice

I'm triyng to set the Sdk environment for LibreOffice and I found these lines in the script:

```
# The SDK name
OO_SDK_NAME=@OO_SDK_NAME@
export OO_SDK_NAME
```

What is the meaning of the at sign (@) before and after the variable "OO_SDK_NAME"?

Best wishes and thanks in advance.

Comment: Read http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/install.html

Comment: "The automatically started configure script (Unix and Windows2000/XP) requests relevant information and directories (SDK, LibreOffice, GNU make, Java, C++), in order to prepare a working SDK environment. After completing the configure script once, the newly created script is always used to set the necessary environment variables for using the SDK and the required tools."